# (Laravel) tables relationship and usage of foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a migration with three tables and i have a question which decide the how the tables will connect to each other and do i really a foreign key on them so what i want to do I have two roles 1 admin - 2 user and i want to assign one of them to each user because i want only admin users to login into backend dashboard as for now i make the relationship between roles and users as one(role)-to-many(users) Also the relationship between posts and users is one(user)-to-many(posts) since the post in only related to one user only but the user can have multiple posts so i need you help here to understand those thing in better way and when i need to setup a Foreign Key in the table.

This is my tables:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: roles doesn't need a user_id column, to get users post you just have to add a method in your user model & define the ->hasMany(class::App\Post) in there

Comment: Thanks ahmad but There is no way someone will do this get post from user_id in roles table i have to be done through user model also i only will user roles to check when login if the user type is an admin or not nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I am understanding, you have three tables: roles, users, and posts.

Whenever you have a relationship like a one-to-many, the table corresponding to the many side will contain the foreign key to the table corresponding to the one side. You do not put any foreign key in the other table.

Now the roles and user table share a one-to-many relationship respectively, thus you put the `role_id` in the user table and do not put any foreign key in the roles table. Similarly, the posts table is on the many side of the relationship (one user can have MANY posts) so you have to put `user_id` in the posts table but no foreign key in the user table.

After you do create the migrations, to be able to query in between the tables, you need to define model files. These model files will contain methods used to retrieve associated records. For a one-to-many relationship, you will be required to have two models (for both tables) and in those models use functions as: `belongsTo` for the table with the foreign key, and a `hasMany` function for the table without the foreign key. For your case, the user model will have a `hasMany` function for the posts model, and a `belongsTo` function for the roles model.

Hope that clears it up

Comment: Thanks for the info Muhammad so the final setup will look like this
https://codeshare.io/an4xpn

Comment: @FahadAlDaferi exactly!